# Should I switch from Mechanise to Scrapy or BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, google-shopping-api

I'm trying to build a web scraper to scrape Google shopping results. Any ideas where to start? I was using mechanize with python but I've found it has some limitations. Would Scrapy or BeautifulSoup be better?

Comment: I'm voting to close, as I think this is too broad (as per the Help Centre). But can you tell us what limitations you encountered in Mechanise, so that the advice is relevant to you?

Comment: well I hit speed boundaries with mechanize that was my biggest limitation.

Comment: @Shajo - the bold/italic/inline-code tools are cool, but we prefer book-style writing here. Code formatting is only for code, and bold/italics should be used sparingly, where emphasis is really required.

Comment: Kirk, you should determine what the bottleneck was with the speed boundaries. If it is CPU/network bound, moving to another library may not help. Or maybe Google was throttling results to your IP?

Comment: Thanks for the edit feedback Shajo!

Comment: @Shajo, additionally: please stop adding "thanks in advance" to posts that do not feature it. We _remove_ that here when we see it, as it is not relevant to the post. Please see _Meta_ for more on that. You are making a lot of edits, it might be worth slowing down for a bit!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Posted on behalf of the OP.*

I found this article to be helpful :

http://swizec.com/blog/scraping-with-mechanize-and-beautifulsoup/swizec/5039

I was getting throttling from the Google side.